# DropdownButton is always disabled

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm putting a DropdownButton in a TileList's trailing, settings up the parameters shown in the docs to make it active, but It stays disabled regardless.

The ListTile is part of a ListView not included in the code below.
I set up setState() like the docs stated but no avail.
I am not able to find the root cause of this issue, no idea what's causing it.

I've tried enum with int as a value but it also didn't work.

```dart
...

final Store<AppState> store;
Units unit;

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   unit = store.state.weatherState?.temperature?.unit;
}

...

enum Units {Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin}

Widget _displayUnitsSettings({Store<AppState> store}) {
    return ListTile(
      dense: true,
      enabled: true,
      selected: true,
      title: Text(
        "Temperature Unit",
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
            decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.dotted,
            fontSize: 14,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            color: Colors.white),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        "Default: Celsius.\nAvailable units: Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin.",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 9, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.white54),
      ),
      trailing: DropdownButton(
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: Colors.white54),
        isDense: true,
        value: unit,
        onChanged: (value) {
          store.dispatch(ChangeUnit(unit: value));
          setState(() {
            unit = value;
          });
        },
        items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: Units.Celsius,
            child: Text("Celsius"),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: Units.Fahrenheit,
            child: Text("Fahrenheit"),
          ),
          DropdownMenuItem(
            value: Units.Kelvin,
            child: Text("Kelvin"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
...
```

**EDIT:** The DropdownButton seem to be enabled but I am unable to click it.

Comment: 1. Not related: you shouldn't use methods returning widgets, but make separated Stateless or Stateful widgets.
2. Related: your dropdown works well. What are you wrapping your ListTile with?

Comment: @GaboBrandX Thanks for replying! I'm building my very first app and still learning Dart/Flutter. Note taken though. I'm wrapping the ListTile with a ListView which is wrapped in a Container. I think the DropdownButton is constrained by the ListTile's height that's why I have problems. But I tried putting the DropdownButton in a Container taking all available screen but It didn't work so I don't know. I can link you the entire file on GitHub: https://github.com/HeiligesLicht/Weatheria/blob/master/lib/screens/weatheria_settings.dart

Comment: Excelent! Let me clone your repo, and see what happens.

Comment: You need an API key for OpenWeatherMap and make api/api.json in root folder.
the json contains only {"OpenWeatherMap" : "API_KEY"}

Comment: Cloned your repo and found the issue. Please check my answer. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem. You have an `AppBar` with no position after the `ListView` on a `Stack`. What this mean is that the `AppBar` is overlapping over your `ListView` and therefore intercepting the gestures on your `DropdownButton`.

Wrap your `AppBar` with a `Positioned` widget and it will work. Like this:

```
  Positioned(
    top: 0.0,
    left: 0.0,
    right: 0.0,
    child: AppBar(
      leading: _backButton(context),
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! I'm using the same technique in the main page too. I should fix that there too. Thanks for taking the time to look into it! :)